# What is the way to extract data from Dynamo DB and load into RDBMS?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, etl, data-warehouse, nosql

I need to pull data from OLTP system which uses Dynamo DB and load it into Oracle. How to proceed with this with minimal load on source database.

Answer (score 0):

If minimal load on the DynamoDB is a requirement, you'll need to use DynamoDB streams, then read the data from a stream in 24 hours and put it into Oracle DBMS with your own code: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Otherwise you can get away with just copying data with Data Pipeline: https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/